# Xcode 11. Unable to install app in the simulator

Tags: xcode, simulator

In Xcode 11.1 (11A1027) I unable to install the app in the simulator with iOS 13.1 (17A844).

I tried to reinstall the Xcode and reset a content of the simulator without no luck.

The error code I get is the following:

```
Details

This app could not be installed at this time.
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Could not install at this time.
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. (LSApplicationWorkspaceErrorDomain error -102.)
Domain: LSApplicationWorkspaceErrorDomain
Code: -102
User Info: {
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.home.test";
    Error = RegistrationFailed;
    "_LSFunction" = "-[_LSInstaller _doinstallApplication:atURL:withOptions:installType:notificationJournaller:reply:]";
    "_LSLine" = 627;
}
--
```

Also the springboard of the simulator is empty which is also strange:
[iOS 13 Simulator has no apps installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P4Rp.jpg)

Comment: I have the same problem. I am working with xamarin forms and there are problems to install the app, was going to try just to run an app with Xcode and got this error.

Comment: The official version of Xcode 11.1 has been released recently. I will try with it.

Comment: I am facing the same issue!!!

Answer (score -2):

Confirmed. It worked for me in the official release of Xcode 11.1